# What is the meaning of "stark" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "This meeting between these two peoples (Thule and Dorset) would have been **a very stark
>   meeting**," Fitzhugh said, "between people with very conservative,
>   beautiful stone technology and beautiful artwork and so on, but
>   socially and economically, they were just no match for this onslaught
>   from this Thule machine. ... They were, in a sense, sitting ducks."

Source: https://www.nbcnews.com/science/science-news/dorset-dna-genes-trace-tale-arctics-long-gone-hobbits-n191156

"Stark" has several meanings, so I couldn't understand which one applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article suggests the Thule people/culture wiped out the Dorset people, so

> [2. harsh, grim, or desolate, as a view, place, etc.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stark)

where grim is

> [4. fierce, savage, or cruel:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/grim)